# Issue displaying SQL rows on a web page

Tags: php, html, sql

Having difficulty displaying rows in an SQL table.

I'm trying to create a comments system for a friend's website. Everything is connected properly and the SQL database is receiving input data, as well as sending it to the web page.

I have a 'foreach' loop which I suspect is the culprit: the loop is displaying a comment with no information on it, as a result of there BEING no information on the iteration of the loop.

I'm sure there's an obvious mistake which is staring me at the face, but I can't see it.

Here's the relevant code:

```
    <ul>
    <?php 
        include "../include/connect.php";
        $get = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username, date, comment FROM comments");

        while($rows[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get));
        if(count($rows) > 0) {
            foreach($rows as $row) {
                $username = $row['username'];
                $date = $row['date'];
                $comment = $row['comment'];
                echo("
                    <li>
                    <article>
                      <header>
                        <figure class=\"avatar\"><img src=\"../images/demo/avatar.png\"></figure>
                        <address>
                        By <span style=\"color:lightblue;\">$username</span>
                        </address>
                        <p>$date</p>
                      </header>
                      <div class=\"comcont\">
                        <p>$comment</p>
                      </div>
                    </article>
                  </li>
                ");
            }
        }
    ?>

    </ul>
```

The web page we're trying to deal with is here:

http://lenslord.co.uk/pages/Testimonials.php

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't use `while` *and* a `foreach`.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that? What should I be using instead? Thanks! :)

Comment: use one *or* the other, not both.

Comment: Simply do: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) { ...all your code that's currently inside the foreach... }`

Comment: IT WORKED! THANK YOU! Can't believe I didn't think of it myself

Comment: @MagnusEriksson and I welcome you ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You said it first, though :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson well, if an answer is to be submitted, it should be a community wiki. It has been answered in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in comments, don't use a `while` *and* a `foreach`.

Use one or the other, not both.

Magnus suggested:

> while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) { ...all your code that's currently inside the foreach... }

Comment: I didn't want to gain rep from this; since it was answered / solved in comments.

Comment: Although [cale_b's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46976991/1415724) is more descriptive than this one.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yepper! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You've introduced some complexity that is unnecessary, and is likely the cause for the issues you are facing.

From your current code:

```
while( $rows[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get) ) {
```

Gets a *single row* from the database, and adds it to an unknown index in the `$rows` variable.  This `while` will run as many times as there are rows in the result set.

Then:

```
    if( count($rows) > 0) {
```

Says "if there are any records in the `$rows` array.  We *know* there are, because you *just put one in there*.

Then:

```
        foreach( $rows as $row ) {
```

Says "loop over all the records in the `$rows` array.   This is also unnecessary, and is causing complexity.

This should be simplified to just be:

```
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $get ) ) {
    $username = $row['username'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    // ... etc
 }
```

Comment: I wanted to say that I did upvote your answer for its detailed explanation.

Comment: @Fred-ii-- Thanks.  I would have loved to try to jam this into a comment - it was clear (to me) some explanation would help - but it wouldn't fit.  I'm glad to "Community Wiki" this, I didn't actually do it for rep... :)  (I don't know how to do that, though... do I have enough rep?)

Comment: Oh, I know you didn't do it for the rep. I found that yours was more fitting an answer and robust. You've explained it well and that's a good thing. I posted the wiki because it was solved in comments and I'm sure you were busy/taking the time to write up a proper answer. You're an asset to Stack. *Cheers* and you're welcome.

Comment: *"(I don't know how to do that, though... do I have enough rep?)"* - In response to that: sure you can. Under the area where you post an answer, you should be able to see a checkbox and "community wiki" next to it. Once you click the checkmark, you then click on "Post Your Answer". I do have to say that once you do that, you can't turn it back to a non-wiki anymore. However you can do the reverse by changing a non-wiki answer to a wiki answer. Just thought you might like to know that beforehand.